# Failed to send request receive response over soap SAML 2.0 Artifact resolution

Tags: c#, xml, soap, saml-2.0

I am working on SAML 2.0. I am getting the following error when trying to request for artifact resolution to idp.

> Failed to send request receive response over soap:The 'meta' start tag
>   on line 5 position 6 does not match the end tag of 'head'. Line 12,
>   position 3.

Following is the code to request artifact resolution to idp:

```
Saml2ArtifactType0004 httpArtifact = Saml2ArtifactType0004.CreateFromHttpArtifactHttpForm(context.Request);
// Saml2ArtifactType0004 httpArtifact = Saml2ArtifactType0004.CreateFromHttpArtifactQueryString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);
// Create an artifact resolve request.
ArtifactResolve artifactResolve = new ArtifactResolve();
artifactResolve.Issuer = new Issuer(Util.GetAbsoluteUrl(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, "~/"));
artifactResolve.Artifact = new Artifact(httpArtifact.ToString());

// Send the artifact resolve request and receive the artifact response.
string spArtifactResponderUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArtifactIdProviderUrl"];

ArtifactResponse artifactResponse = ArtifactResponse.SendSamlMessageReceiveAftifactResponse(spArtifactResponderUrl, artifactResolve);

// Extract the authentication request from the artifact response.
samlResponse = new Response(artifactResponse.Message);
relayState = httpArtifact.RelayState;
```

The artifact resolve xml is as follows:

```
<saml:ArtifactResolve ID="_37DBE1945FEE46AFA8760669A9E35A71" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-06-07T05:53:15.756Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://localhost:1426/</saml:Issuer><samlp:Artifact xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">AAQAAErbp/tMatqZ/zZ4dvK10H8AAAAAvYu+k6ffUkCCUnLjx2ixkwAAAAA=</samlp:Artifact></saml:ArtifactResolve>
```

Can anyone help me with the error?